# How to compose a rotation matrix with Euler Data?

Tags: modeling, animation, animation-nodes

[image: Current SetUp]

The picture is my current set up. From the data set of Euler angles in the text editor, I would expect the object to rotate ~10, 20, 30,... degrees around the X axis, but it rotates noticeably larger than the input angles. Does anyone have any ideas as to what I am doing wrong? I am currently using AnimationNodes.

Comment: I don't use Animation Nodes, so I'm not at all sure about this, but shouldn't the values be given in radians rather than degrees? 10 radians is aproximately 573 degrees, i.e. one and a half full turn and another 33 degrees. From your image I'm guessing that's about the amount your object has rotated.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [Duane](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98551/how-to-compose-a-rotation-matrix-with-euler-data#comment-174463) It probably has something to do with your units.

The *Combine Euler* node supports composing eulers from degrees as well as radians, check the [documentation](http://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/rotation/combine_euler.html):

[image: Euler]

It is worth mentioning that parsing can be easily done in Animation Nodes as:

[image: Parsing]